# Как сохранить настройки видеопроцессора в C#

Tags: c#, web-camera, aforge

Мне потребовалось сохранить все настройки веб камеры и для этого я использовал библиотеку AForge, настройки самой вебкамеры содержат в себе две вкладки:
"Усилитель видеопроцессора" и "Управление камерой"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот, библиотека AForge содержит в себе

```
bool VideoCaptureDevice.GetCameraProperty(CameraControlProperty property, out int val, out CameraControlFlags controlFlags)
```

которая возвращает настройки только вкладки "Управление камерой", при этом где-то на просторах сети, а т.е. на сайте самого AForge я видел метод `GetVideoProperty` который якобы должен возвращать настройки с первой вкладки, но его в моей сборке, видимо нет (версия кстати 2.2.5.0)

Так вот в чём сообственно вопрос: Если такая сторонняя или стандартная либа, которая позволит сохранить настройки видеопроцессора? т.е. яркость, контрастность, оттенок и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл ответ на свой же вопрос, в тех же просторах интернета
Существует такая библиотека DirectShow.NET, в которой возможен такой способ получения и проставления тех или иных настроек видеопроцессора

```
object o;
Guid IID_IBaseFilter = new Guid("56a86895-0ad4-11ce-b03a-0020af0ba770");
__videoDevices[index].Mon.BindToObject(null, null, ref IID_IBaseFilter, out o);
IAMVideoProcAmp procAmp = (IAMVideoProcAmp)o;
int someval = 0;
VideoProcAmpFlags fl;

procAmp.Get(VideoProcAmpProperty.Contrast, out someval, out fl);
procAmp.Set(VideoProcAmpProperty.Brightness, 10, VideoProcAmpFlags.Manual);
```